# Check if a date exists in a pandas dataframe

Tags: pandas

```
                  Date Signal
1  2008-05-28 11:00:00   1.886108
2  2008-04-17 12:00:00   1.885108
3  2008-05-21 12:00:00   1.166525
4  2008-05-28 11:00:00   1.166525
5  2008-05-23 11:00:00   1.010902
```

Hi, is there a way I can match the above dataframe to a date, eg `2008-05-28 11:00:00` and print only the `Signal` value if it matches? 
thanks in advance. 
* apologies if this was a niave question.  I tried many various methods but not .loc which has been kindly pointed out below and works perfectly, thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have data frame `df`

```
d = pandas.Timestamp("2008-05-28 11:00:00", tz=None)
df[df.Date == d].Signal
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `loc` too:

```
df.loc[df.Date == '2008-05-28 11:00:00', 'Signal']
```

Answer (score 0):

Not tested but something along the lines of...

```
df['Signal'][df.Date == '2008-05-28 11:00:00']
```